Как настроить сетевую видимость между двумя адаптерами
Имеется ПК с Windows 11, на нем установлен Docker Desktop и wsl2 с Ubuntu. На убунте крутятся контейнеры с zabbix.
По мануалу с оф. сайта zabbix была создана подсеть docker network create --subnet 172.20.0.0/16 --ip-range 172.20.240.0/20 zabbix-net в режиме bridge.
Веб-консоль zabbix доступна как по адресу 172.22.121.50, так и по локальному адресу ПК 192.168.50.140, но из сети 172.22 не видны устройства в сети 192.168.
Прошу подсказать что и куда необходимо прописать, чтобы устройства в сети 192.168 видели zabbix-сервер в сети 172.22 ?

Docker Desktop не умеет маршрутизировать виртуальные сети: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible
Единственный способ достучаться до контейнера - через отмапленные порты: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-to-a-container-from-the-host

они из 192.168. не должны видеть 172.22. если нужен какой-то сервис  пробрасывайте порты через докер.
